DATABASE_ROUTERS in Django settings for multiple DBs
In my Django Rest Framework(DRF) project, I have multiple apps (say app1, app2 & app3).
Till now they all were referring to same DB, which was mentioned under default.
Now I need to add another app, app4, that would be using a separate DB, say new_db.
To include that, I have updated DATABASES to below:

{
'default': DEFAULT_PARAMS, 
'new_db': CUSTOM_PARAMS
}

DEFAULT_PARAMS and CUSTOM_PARAMS both contains DICTIONARY as value for their respective DATABASE.
Now mentioning the app_label under model's Meta class should be enough, but by default it's reaching out to the default DB. Have checked the same by creating a common table earlier when it was not in default DB it was giving error on table_name but after it was created I was able to fetch the data.
Is there some other way that we can refer to the tables in other DB? I am not in favor of using DATABASE_ROUTERS, are there other ways we can do this without creating the routers?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

@anupsabraham this still needs us to add dB name explicitly. I don't understand what's the use of mentioning app_label in models meta, if we are doing this

app_label is used to tell django which app the model belongs to. It doesn't have anything to do with database routing. For that, you'll need DATABASE_ROUTERS to be configured. Which is straightforward. Or the other option is to select the database whenever you do a query. I understand that is very cumbersome.
Can you explain why you don't want to go with the DATABASE_ROUTERS approach?
